# mysql returns junk value when querying for the week value

Tags: mysql

```
select (SELECT power FROM newdb.newmeter where date(dt)=curdate() order by dt desc limit 1)
-(select Power from newdb.newmeter where date(dt)=(select date(subdate(now(), interval weekday(now()) day))) limit 0,1) as difference;
```

The above query is part of my prog which gives me difference in data being stored from day 1 of the week to the current day of the week. Those queries individually works fine as below, and returns:

```
SELECT power FROM newdb.newmeter where date(dt)=curdate() order by dt desc limit 1;
```

result: 941690 current time

```
select Power from newdb.newmeter where date(dt)=(select date(subdate(now(), interval weekday(now()) day))) limit 0,1;
```

result 93242.4 at the start of the week (or day for today as its monday)

But as soon as I run the difference query which is just the difference between above two that result in : 848447.8515625

This seems just really strange don't understand whats wrong with it? Please help.

Comment: What is the type of power? And what database is this?

Comment: Power column is type float its very simple sort of database which holds 3 column id(bigint, autoincrement), Power(float), datetime(currenttimestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You don't order by dt in your second query, looking for power at the start of week. Which means you are selecting undefined record that happens to have matching date. For a simple select the table is usually sorted by insert order, but it can change when optimizer thinks it can run a query faster using some other order. Basically, if you don't define order you don't care about order.

Comment: i realised that my question is itself an anwser if you look very close. there is nothing wrong with the querry but thanks any way for all your support i really love this forum...every time i post something i do find an answer somehow......thanks again.         hint: just an easy math on the results will give you an answer cheers hahaha :-))

Answer (score 0):

How many decimal places do you want in the answer? Use DECIMAL(7,1) for Power (I assume you want one decimal place) instead and see what you get.

I tend to avoid floats/doubles as the approximate values can get you into trouble.